# Is there a way to set MemberList.None to all maps?

Tags: c#, automapper

Is there a way to set the flag MemberList.None to all my maps without doing it individually? I'm trying to do this using the following:

```cs
cfg.ForAllMaps((typeMap, _) =>
{
    typeMap.ConfiguredMemberList = MemberList.None;
});
```

But `AutoMapperConfigurationException` is still thrown when calling the method `AssertConfigurationIsValid`.

Comment: Maybe not call `AssertConfigurationIsValid`? :)

Comment: I call it inside a unit test to avoid problems like duplicated mappings.

Comment: AM is designed to work with validation. If someone adds a new member to the destination object, what do you do? I don't see how disabling validation _everywhere_ is useful.

Comment: I just don't care about new members being added to destination members. What I want to check with the unit test is things like if a given map for a class is defined only once to avoid overriding behavior. Because, believe me, this happens a lot.

Comment: It seems like you should write a function that does that, not call `AssertConfigurationIsValid`.

Comment: I got your point but why is that so bad? Since the method will warn me of what is believed to be a problem, I just don't want not mapped members on destination to be one. Principally becaure we're able to individually ignore this on CreateMap using `MemberList.None`. Having a way to set this parameter for all maps, would be very good.

Answer (score 0):

To anyone trying to do something similiar, I just decided to set `MemberList.None` on all `CreateMap` pointed by the exception and my test looks like this:

```cs
[TestClass]
public class AutoMapperTests
{
    [TestMethod]
    public void AssertConfigurationIsValid_DoesntThrowException()
    {
        // Arrange
        var configuration = AutoMapperProvider.Configuration;

        // Act - Assert
        configuration
            .Invoking(c => c.AssertConfigurationIsValid())
            .Should()
            .NotThrow();
    }
}
```